# Decoding objects without knowing their type first

Tags: swift, decoder

There is a likelihood this is an XY problem, I am open to these suggestions as well !

I am trying to work with Minecraft save data. Minecraft encodes Entities (basically anything that is not strictly a block) with their type inside an `id` property . The file then contains a big array of entities, which I want to decode and instantiate.

The problem is that, using `Decodable`, I must know an object's type before I start instantiating it like `container.decode(Zombie.self)`. I can't figure out how to create a function that would read the id and return the right type of entity ?

I think this explains what I need better than any explanation could :

```swift
//Entity objects don't actually store their ID since re-encoding it is trivial.
protocol Entity : Decodable {var someProperty : Int {get set}}
struct Zombie : Entity {var someProperty : Int}
struct Skeleton : Entity {var someProperty : Int}

//Using JSON instead of SNBT so we can use JSONDecoder
let jsonData = """
[
    {
        "id":"zombie",
        "someProperty":"3"
    },
    {
        "id" : "skeleton",
        "someProperty":"3"
    }
]
"""

struct EntityList : Decodable {
    var list : [any Entity] = []
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        //What should we put here ?
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let entityList = try decoder.decode(EntityList.self, from: Data(jsonData.utf8))
//entityList should be [Zombie, Skeleton]
```

At the moment I'm looking into the Factory pattern, maybe that's an interesting lead ? In any case, thank you for your help !

---

( *Please note this question has nothing to do with decoding the actual binary contents of the file, it was honestly quite hard to do but I already have a working `Encoder` / `Decoder`. It is only about unpacking those contents, hence why I just used JSON in the example above, since we have a common `Decoder` for that.* )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly haven't used the new `any` syntax enough to know if that can help but I have done what you're trying to do numerous times and here is how I do it.

### Set up the data first

We first declare what a `Zombie` and a `Skeleton` are. They could just inherit from a protocol or they could be separate structs...

```
struct Zombie: Decodable {
  let someProperty: Int
}

struct Skeleton: Decodable {
  let someProperty: Int
  let skeletonSpecificProperty: String
}
```

Then we can turn your array of `[anyEntityType]` into a homogeneous array by using an enum and embedding the entities into it...

```
enum Entity: Decodable {
  case zombie(Zombie)
  case skeleton(Skeleton)
}
```

### Decode the enum given your JSON structure

We have to provide a custom decoder for the `Entity` type...

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RootKeys.self)

  // First get the `id` value from the JSON object
  let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)

  // check the value for each type of entity we can decode
  switch type {

  // for each value of `id` create the related type
  case "zombie":
    let zombie = try Zombie(from: decoder)
    self = .zombie(zombie)
  case "skeleton":
    let skeleton = try Skeleton(from: decoder)
    self = .skeleton(skeleton)
  default:
    // throw an error here... unsupported type or something
  }
}
```

This should now let you decode an array of Entities from JSON into an `[Entity]` array.

### Deal with "unknown" types

There is an extra step required for dealing with the "unknown" types. For instance, in the code above. If the JSON contains `"id": "creeper"` this will error as it can't deal with that. And you'll end up with your whole array failing to decode.

I've created a couple of helper functions that help with that...

If you create an object like...

```
struct Minecraft: Decodable {
  let entities: [Entity]

  enum RootKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case entities
  }
}
```

And these helpers...

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
  func decodeAny<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> [T] {
    var items = try nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)

    var itemsArray: [T] = []
    while !items.isAtEnd {
      guard let item = try? items.decode(T.self) else {
        try items.skip()
        continue
      }
      itemsArray.append(item)
    }
    return itemsArray
  }
}

private struct Empty: Decodable { }

extension UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
  mutating func skip() throws {
    _ = try decode(Empty.self)
  }
}
```

You can create a custom decoder for the `Minecraft` type like this...

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RootKeys.self)
  self.entities = try container.decodeAny(Entity.self, forKey: .entities)
}
```

Comment: Using an enum for entity seems sensible since I'll have to switch off of them anyways ! Great idea. The hard part really is that for some reason they chose to put the type in with the rest of the data. Honestly though all their data structures are pretty weird, for one they don't seem to enforce any naming conventions so variables like `XpP`, `WanderingTraderSpawnDelay`, `seenCredits` and `warden_spawn_tracker` all live in the same object...

Comment: I could maybe just dump all the data in some sort of temporary structure and give it to the entity's initializer ? Maybe there's even something smart to do with tuples so we don't have to manually wire everything together ?

Comment: @Crysambrosia updated. There's a lot of boilerplate here. But doing this up front means that you can fairly easily add new types to your enum and decode them from the JSON as you go.

Comment: Don't worry I'm not scared of boilerplate anymore, this thing is such a mess I've had to make decode and encode methods by hand with hundreds of properties :'-) A few questions though : 1) Wouldn't it be easier to add a `unknown` case to the enum that just stores the `id` as a property ? 2) How does this solve the issue that decoders are only supposed to produce a `container` once ? (you are passing down the decoder directly which means each entity is going to ask for a new container)

Comment: 1. Yes, you could do that. You would end up with a lot of `.unknown` in your array. But you could filter them out. 2. I honestly did not know about that ... 

Comment: @Crysambrosia do you have a link for info about Decoders only creating a single container?

Comment: 1. Well, at first I would, but ultimately outside of modded worlds that shouldn't happen once I'm done defining all the entities. 2. I'm probably going to try my "dump out the data, then initialise" idea then ! The problem is the "only one container" requirement is runtime only, so it's fairly easy to miss, but your code is going to `preconditionFailure` if I remember the JSONDecoder source correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247319/discussion-between-crysambrosia-and-fogmeister).

Comment: I've run this in a playground and it seems to work fine. ‍♂️ Def worth giving a try. Once it's set up it's much easier to add to.

Comment: Leaving this here for posterity : while `Encoder`s are only supposed to give one container, `Decoder`s do not care. The requirement is only checked at runtime though, so beware `Encoder`s !